# I would like to turn off the tablet mode in Windows 10 programmatically

Tags: windows, mfc

I am developing applications based on a Windows 10 with MFC.

However, Because Tablet mode on, When Click EditControl, Tiptap.exe is Turn On.

I want Turn off Tiptap.exe, Tablet mode (in Windows 10)

How do I Turn Off the tablet mode in programmatically ?

Comment: As far as I can read the docs, this is not possible from the API.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.uiviewsettings The property is just read only.

Answer (score 0):

Responding to gestures and other touch device specific things in an MFC application is simple. All modern versions of MFC starting from version 10 (VS 2010) do support the `WM_GESTURE` Windows message out of the box. The MFC translates the various panning, zooming and rotating gestures that are all encapsulated by `WM_GESTURE` into distinct `CWnd` virtual methods like `OnGestureZoom` and `OnGestureRotate` that take care of the parsing of the information in the `WM_GESTURE` parameters into specific information relevant to the gesture.

The MFC Gesture `CWnd` virtual functions are:

- `OnGestureZoom(CPoint ptCenter, long lDelta)`
- `OnGesturePan(CPoint ptFrom, CPoint ptTo)`
- `OnGestureRotate(CPoint ptCenter, double dblAngle)`
- `OnGestureTwoFingerTap(CPoint ptCenter)`
- `OnGesturePressAndTap(CPoint ptPress, long lDelta)`

Registering to receive the low-level touch messages which may be coming from multiple touch points simultaneously, and responding to these touch events in the message handler is done via `CWnd::OnTouchInput`:

```
virtual BOOL OnTouchInput(CPoint pt, int nInputNumber, int nInputsCount, PTOUCHINPUT pInput);
```